# JScrollPane adding items Horizontally, but I want them added vertically

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am creating a bespoke table that I want to scroll up and down, so I am using JScrollPane.

My problem is that each time I add another row in the table it is adding it to the side of the last one, rather than below the last line, which is where I want it to be. Eg it is adding columns to the table rather than rows.

The number of rows that need to be added is uncertain and depends on how many entries there are in the table.

I know I can use a table but for the purposes of this exercise I want to do it this way.

Below is an MCVE version of my code that demonstrates the problem. I left the colour change in so the fields are more visible:

```
public class Customers {


     public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

     public static void frameGui(JPanel panel, String name){

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            frame.setContentPane(panel);

            frame.setSize(1200,500);

            frame.setVisible(true);
     }



     public static void ScrollCustomersGui(){           

            JPanel Table = new JPanel();

            Table.add(customersTableHeadings(Table));
            Table.add(customersTableHeadings(Table));  
            Table.add(customersTableHeadings(Table));  

            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(Table);

            JPanel All = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            All.add(scroll);

            frameGui(All, "Customers");
        }

    public static JPanel customersTableHeadings(JPanel panel){

         FlowLayout FlowCustTable = (FlowLayout)panel.getLayout();
         FlowCustTable.setHgap(0);

         JPanel customersTable = new JPanel(FlowCustTable);

         JTextField custid = new JTextField("ONE");
         custid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
         custid.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

         customersTable.add(custid);

         return customersTable;

    }





}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use vertical BoxLayout here is the modified code :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Customers
{

    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static void frameGui(JPanel panel, String name)
    {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setSize(1200, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void ScrollCustomersGui()
    {
        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        //JPanel Table = new JPanel();
        //Table.setLayout(new BoxLayout(Table, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        box.add(customersTableHeadings());
        box.add(customersTableHeadings());
        box.add(customersTableHeadings());

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(box);

        JPanel All = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        All.add(scroll);

        frameGui(All, "Customers");
    }

    public static JPanel customersTableHeadings()
    {
        // FlowLayout FlowCustTable = (FlowLayout) panel.getLayout();
        // FlowCustTable.setHgap(0);

        JPanel customersTable = new JPanel();
        customersTable.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(550, 60));

        JTextField custid = new JTextField("ONE");
        custid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        custid.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        customersTable.add(custid);

        return customersTable;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ScrollCustomersGui();
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I remve the spaces between the rows. I was using setHgap(0) previously

Comment: @jim BoxLayout use the maximum size of the component it contains, so to minimize to gape between added components you should use setMaximumSize(Dimension) of the new added panel. (NB: setMaximumSize is already used in the given modified code see method customersTableHeadings)

Answer (score 1):

you are using a FlowLayout which will not work for your case you can use a BoxLayout check it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html), you can also use a GridBagLayout but it is complex :)